# push back eigen C++ block expression into std::vector

Tags: templates, c++14, eigen

I would like to create a utility function that takes in an Eigen Matrix and a std::vector of the same size as the number of rows as the matrix.

The result should be a std::vector of row references to the rows of the input matrix.

See the code snippet below for the trivial case of how the function should be implemented:

```
template<typename RowReferenceType, typename MatrixType>
std::vector<RowReferenceType> getReferencedRows(MatrixType& matrix, const std::vector<bool>& addRow)
{
    assert(matrix.rows() == addRow.size());
    std::vector<RowReferenceType> rows;
    for(size_t i = 0; i < addRow.size(); ++i)
    {
        if(addRow[i])
            rows.push_back(matrix.row(i));
    }
    return rows;
}
```

The code above will not compile for numerous reasons such as type deduction failure. We could specify the types but I would prefer the caller of the function to only specify the matrix and std::vector in the parameters of the function.

Here is an example of the expected output of the function:

```
Eigen::MatrixXd V(4, 3);
V <<
    0.5, 0.3, 0.2,
    0.46, 0.88, 0.99,
    0.46, 0.88, 0.99,
    0.46, 0.88, 0.99;

std::vector<bool> referenceRow{ false, true, false, true};
auto rows = getReferencedRows<Eigen::Block<Eigen::MatrixXd>, Eigen::MatrixXd>(V, referenceRow);
for(auto& r : rows)
{
    r = Eigen::RowVector3d{ 0,0,0 };
}
```

In the above code snippet, rows 1 and 3 will be changed to zero vectors ergo `V` is directly modified by the assignment expression `r = Eigen::RowVector3d{ 0,0,0 };`

Here is my first attempt at having template type deduction do more work:

```
template<typename Scalar, int Rows, int Cols>
std::vector<Eigen::Block<Eigen::Matrix<Scalar, Rows, Cols>, Rows, Cols>> getReferenceRows(Eigen::Matrix<Scalar, Rows, Cols>& matrix, const std::vector<bool>& addRow)
{
    assert(matrix.rows() == addRow.size());
    std::vector<Eigen::Block<Eigen::Matrix<Scalar, Rows, Cols>, Rows, Cols>> rows;
    for(size_t i = 0; i < addRow.size(); ++i)
    {
        if(addRow[i])
        {
            auto block = matrix.row(i);
            rows.push_back(block);
        }
    }
    return rows;
}
```

The problem with the code above is I am still unable to deduce the template parameteres for the `Eigen::Block<...>` expression to push back into the `std::vector`.

I was also looking into using `Eigen::ref<...>` but I run into the same issues.

Answer (score 0):

Solved indirectly by using `Eigen::Ref`

```
template<typename Scalar, int Rows, int Cols>
using EigenReferenceRowVector = Eigen::Ref<Eigen::Matrix<Scalar, Rows, Cols>, 0, Eigen::InnerStride<>>;

template<typename Scalar, int Rows, int Cols>
std::vector<EigenReferenceRowVector<Scalar, 1, Cols>> getReferencedRows(Eigen::Matrix<Scalar, Rows, Cols>& matrix, const std::vector<bool>& addRow)
{
    std::vector<EigenReferenceRowVector<Scalar, 1, Cols>> rows;
    assert(addRow.size() == matrix.rows());
    for(int i = 0; i < addRow.size(); ++i)
    {
        if (addRow[i])
            rows.push_back(matrix.row(i));
    }
    return rows;
}
```

And output:

```
Eigen::MatrixXd V(4, 3);
V <<
    0.5, 0.3, 0.2,
    0.46, 0.88, 0.99,
    0.46, 0.88, 0.99,
    0.46, 0.88, 0.99;

std::vector<bool> referenceRow{ false, true, false, true };
auto rows = getReferencedRows(V, referenceRow);
for(auto& r : rows)
{
    r = Eigen::RowVector3d{ 0,0,0 };
}
std::cout << V;
```

This answer is suboptimal as each matrix type needs to have its own `Eigen::Ref<...>` vector reference type defined and each function overloaded to return the appropriate type.